# How can I write this link as a button/click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, hyperlink

Here is the link -

```
<a data-op="database" data-id="'+ entry.id +'">Save to database</a>
```

Just want it as a button rather than a link.

Comment: `button` instead of `a`?

Comment: If changing `a` element to `button` is not possible, try `$('a[data-op]').on('click', function() { return false; });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like that :) :

`<button data-op="database" data-id="'+ entry.id +'">Save to database</button>`

Answer (score 2):

`<button data-op="database" data-id="'+ entry.id +'">Save to database</button>`

```
$('button[data-op]').on('click', function() { 
    console.log('data-op is clicked'); 
    return false;
});
```